# Problem connecting Reporting Services 2005 to Progress OpenEdge 10.2A Driver

Tags: sql-server-2005, odbc, reportingservices-2005, progress-4gl, openedge

Background:
Progress based ERP system called QAD 2008.1 (formerly MFGPRO.
SQL Server 2005 Enterprise SP2.
Reporting Services 2005 SP2.
Progress OpenEdge 10.2A Driver.
ODBC System DSN created using the Progress OpenEdge 10.2A Driver.

Problem:
I am creating a report with Reporting Services and will need to use the Progress OpenEdge 10.2A driver as a data source view.

The error is the following:  Error [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver] Insufficient information to connect to the data source.

Yet the ODBC connection is created correctly and connects succesfully?!!?

I cannot create the data source view at all. I have checked on the Progress, DataDirect and OpenLink forums and have found nothing!

I appreciate your effort and help with this question. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to log into the database with the user that starts the DB and create a DBA user. Execute the following statements:

```
CREATE USER 'usernameToConnectAs','';
GRANT DBA TO usernameToConnectAs;
```